# A question about the sequence of holomorphic vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

In Huybrechts"Complex Geometry"P93,he wrote:"a sequence of holomorphic vector bundles $0\rightarrow E\rightarrow F\rightarrow G\rightarrow 0$ is exact if and only if $0\rightarrow G^*\rightarrow F^*\rightarrow E^* \rightarrow 0$ is exact.

As we know,for all $x \in U_i\cap U_j$ the matrix of $\{ \psi^{'}_{ij} \}$ has the form $\begin{bmatrix} \psi_{ij}&* \\ 0& \phi_{ij}  \end{bmatrix}$ ,then $E$ is a holomorphic sub-bundle of $F$, i.e. there exist a canonical injection $E \subset F$.

Conversely if $E$ is a sub-bundle of $F$ we can find cocycles of this form and the cokernel $F/E$ is described by the cocycles $\phi_{ij}$.

S0,For $F^*$,the matrix of $(\{ \psi^{'}_{ij} \}^{-1})^{T}$ has the form $\begin{bmatrix} (\{ \psi_{ij} \}^{-1})^{T}&0 \\ *^{'}& (\{ \phi_{ij} \}^{-1})^{T}\end{bmatrix}$ .

I wonder that why the claim is not "$0\rightarrow E^*\rightarrow F^*\rightarrow G^* \rightarrow 0$ is exact"?

Note that a morphism of vector bundle is uniquely determined by a collection of holomorphic maps 
$$\lbrace f_i: U_i \longrightarrow\mathcal{M}_{m\times n}(\mathbb{C}) \rbrace_i $$ such that $f_i=(\{\psi^{'}_{ij} \}^{-1})^{T}f_j(\{ \psi_{ji} \}^{-1})^{T}$. At this point I can define $$f_i=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbb{I}_m\\
O \\
 \end{array} \right].$$

I prefer a detailed explanation,thanks a lot!

Comment: It may not be difficult to find examples in Huybrechts books where $0\rightarrow E^*\rightarrow F^*\rightarrow G^* \rightarrow 0$ is not exact although $0\rightarrow E\rightarrow F\rightarrow G \rightarrow 0$ is. In fact, these two sequences are exact at the same time if and only if $E=F\oplus G$.

Comment: If you have a bundle map $E\to F$, how do you define a map $E^*\to F^*$ as you seem to want to suggest? Can you even do this (naturally) for vector spaces? ... At any rate, I would suggest you start with the question for vector spaces and do the linear algebra in that case, rather than worrying about transition functions.

Comment: I think I can see why you're confused, but in your matrix form of the cocycles of $F^{*}$, it's very important that the ($*$) is in the bottom left, not the top right entry.  This is telling you that it's actually $G^{*}$ which is a sub-bundle of $F^{*}$.  The matrix ($*$) should be interpreted as an obstruction to the original sequence splitting *holomorphicaly*.  So as someone commented just above, what you're claiming will happen if and only if $F \cong E \oplus G$ as holomorphic bundles.  (Recall, vector bundles always split topologically).

Comment: Thanks a lot ,all guys!